# how to check css is valid for IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a web site that looks OK in browsers chrome, firefox and IE above 8. 
in IE8 down it doesn't look good. Is there a tool out there to check if my css file is valid for IE8 ?
I would prefer one that will indicate me which lines in my CSS file not valid for IE8 and how to fix them.

Comment: Either CSS is valid or it's not. There's no special IE8 CSS.

Comment: CSS specs are not written with microsoft exemptions, e.g. "all browsers must do X, but IE is allowed to do Y". Either it's valid CSS, or it's not CSS at all.

Comment: W3C CSS Validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: One tool that has done a lot of good for me is [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: validate the css and html in w3c validator

Comment: If your question is "is there a tool that will show me if my CSS will work the way I want in IE8?", the answer is *there isn't*.  The best you can do is find one that will pick out all of the properties and selectors IE8 doesn't support.  Beyond that, it would be impossible for it to correctly pinpoint anything that would cause display irregularities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IE Tester Application.
You can render to different IE Versions. if its not supporting create separate Css for version and target to that version.
http://ietester.en.softonic.com/